# Add nofollow attribute to each <a> tag with external link after the page was rendered

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

Customer has requested, that all links to external pages in our sitecore solution should have a *nofollow* attribute. Which pipeline should I use to have an access to response html (to change the links before they will be delivered with markup to browser)? Or is there any better solution to accomplish this?

JavaScript is not much helpful here because I am not sure if all search engines are able to run JavaScript.

*RenderField* processor is also not usable, due to many custom  tags in our code

Comment: Not an answer, but does your customer have any idea what they're asking for? I'm guessing they're under the impression that while a search engine is crawling your site it might jump out and crawl someone else's instead. Which would be wrong. I'd ask directly what the business case for this is.

Comment: Further to @JamesWalford - some years ago it was common practice by SEO 'professionals' to recommend this to try to prevent the leak of Google PageRank to external sites.  Any benefit that might (might!) have been gleaned from this is long gone.  See [Wikipedia/NoFollow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest
And patch after the ExecuteRequest.

On this point you have the fully rendered html, including all cached components from the HTML cache.

Edit add a Example:

```
#region Using
using System;
using System.IO;

using Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest;

#endregion

namespace MySpace.Sitecore.Pipelines
{

    public class MyProcessor : HttpRequestProcessor
    {

        public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
        {

            if (!global::Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor)
            {
                if (!args.Context.Request.RawUrl.Contains(".") || (args.Context.Request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains(".aspx") && !args.Context.Request.RawUrl.ToLower().StartsWith("/sitecore")))
                {
                    args.Context.Response.Filter = new MyInterestFilter(args.Context.Response.Filter);
                }
            }
        }

        #region Stream filter

        public class MyInterestFilter : Stream
        {

            public MyInterestFilter(Stream sink)
            {
                _sink = sink;
            }

            private Stream _sink;

            #region Properites

            public override bool CanRead
            {
                get { return true; }
            }

            public override bool CanSeek
            {
                get { return true; }
            }

            public override bool CanWrite
            {
                get { return true; }
            }

            public override void Flush()
            {
                _sink.Flush();
            }

            public override long Length
            {
                get { return 0; }
            }

            private long _position;

            public override long Position
            {
                get { return _position; }
                set { _position = value; }
            }

            #endregion

            #region Methods

            public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
            {
                return _sink.Read(buffer, offset, count);
            }

            public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
            {
                return _sink.Seek(offset, origin);
            }

            public override void SetLength(long value)
            {
                _sink.SetLength(value);
            }

            public override void Close()
            {
                _sink.Close();
            }

            public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[count];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, offset, data, 0, count);
                string html = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);

                html = MyReplace(html);

                byte[] outdata = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(html);
                _sink.Write(outdata, 0, outdata.GetLength(0));
            }

            public static string MyReplace(string html)
            {

                 html = html.Replace("TESTSTRING", "REPLACEDTESTSTRING");

                return html;
            }

            #endregion

        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

And set a patch file in the App_Config include directory somethings like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <httpRequestBegin>
        <processor type="MySpace.Sitecore.Pipelines.MyProcessor, MySpace.Sitecore" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest, Sitecore.Kernel']"/>
      </httpRequestBegin>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How can I access and change HTML in processor? Using HttpRequestArgs? Request/Response?

Comment: ... I think, I catched that:. I need to use HttpResponse Filter (am I right?)

Comment: Yep, similar to a HttpModule but now in a Sitecore pipeline. I Add a Example, Works for webForms and I think also for MVC, alternative is a HttpModule.

Comment: Beware of performance impacts of this, although it may work for a small subset of data, you are essentially parsing **all** the output HTML and replacing data. As the output size gets larger, and so the performance impacts gets bigger. As the others have stated the SEO benefit of this is mininal, but the correct place to add this tag is in the `<renderField>` pipeline, it's just an addition to any custom tags that you may be already inserting.

Comment: The Sitecore CDN module is also a Example of the Response.Filter the CDNAttachFilter  see https://github.com/NTTDATA/SitecoreCDN for the code. As @jammykam notice about the performance is true. but as long as you do not do crazy things, the impact is usually okay.

Comment: @JanBluemink That CDN connector is 2 years old and may not have been updated, but it is better to use "Media.MediaLinkServerUrl" instead: https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/domain-sharding-media-requests-in-sitecore/ As you stated, the Filter works on cached components as well. Better to run your logic earlier so that the final HTML (with `nofollow` tag) is also cached and therefore only run once rather than every request.

Comment: As @jammykam pointed out watch out for performance issues with the server side approach.  I would be inclined to go for a javascript approach similar to that outlined in [Adding the nofollow attribute to external links with jQuery](http://andymatthews.net/read/2009/01/14/Adding-the-nofollow-attribute-to-external-links-with-jQuery).

Comment: I use a Response.Filter for replacing realtime data, for that case it is correct to replace also cached html, About the performance it cost lesser than 1 ms. minify HTML is also a case where such Filters are used.